# Uncaught TypeError: yearsList is undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to write some piece of javascript code in a react project. I have a component "expenses" which has been passed some data by props. data is an array of some objects. here is my code:
the data:

```
    const EXPENSES = [
  { id: "e1", date: "March 2021 12", description: "New TV", price: "$780" },
  { id: "e2", date: "April 2020 19", description: "basket", price: "$860" },
  { id: "e3", date: "June 2021 08", description: "Laptop", price: "$59" },
];
```

and inside my expenses component:

```
const yearsList = props.data.map((item) => item.date.split(" ")[1]);
  console.log(yearsList); //it prints ["2021" , "2020" , 2021] as expected

  const finalYearsList = (yearsList) => {
    var temp = [];
    var j = 0;
    for (let i = 0; i < yearsList.length; i++) { //this line: Uncaught TypeError: yearsList is undefined
      if (temp.includes(yearsList[i])) {
        continue;
      } else {
        temp[j++] = yearsList[i];
      }
    }
    return temp.sort();
  };
```

I want to have all non-repeated years in my finalYearList const but it gives me an error in console that Uncaught TypeError: yearsList is undefined. I'm a bit new to the javascript world. thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are shadowing the `yearsList` variable that you declare on line 1 with the parameter `yearsList` in line 4.

You could change your code in two ways:

1. Remove the parameter on line 4, so your function declaration is

```
const finalYearsList = () => {
  ...
}
```

2. Pass in `yearsList` as a parameter when you call the function `finalYearsList`

```
const yearsList = props.data.map( ... );

const finalYearsList = (yearsList) => {
  ...
}

finalYearsList(yearsList);
```

A recommendation I'd make if you go with option number 2 is to rename either the variable or the parameter and avoid this shadowing altogether, as it causes confusion (as you've seen).

Comment: omg . I can't believe that I did this mistake. yes sounds reasonable and solved my problem. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use your yearsList in the function finalYearsList, you don't have to pass it as an argument. In your current code you are declaring a parameter with the name yearsList and you thereby overwrite the original yearsList.

Your original yearsList is defined in the global scope and therefore accessible inside of every function !

So just use...

```
const yearsList = props.data.map((item) => item.date.split(" ")[1]);
  console.log(yearsList); //it prints ["2021" , "2020" , 2021] as expected

  const finalYearsList = () => {
    var temp = [];
    var j = 0;
    for (let i = 0; i < yearsList.length; i++) { //this line: Uncaught TypeError: yearsList is undefined
      if (temp.includes(yearsList[i])) {
        continue;
      } else {
        temp[j++] = yearsList[i];
      }
    }
    return temp.sort();
  };
```

...instead.